# Flex 4 Disappearing Labels with Embedded Fonts and Charts

Tags: flex4, flex4.5, embedded-fonts

I'm using an embedded font in Flex 4, which on its own seems to work perfectly. I then added some charts and specified the -fteInMXComponents compiler option to get the embedded font in the charts. When I did this, the axis values in the charts disappeared.

I'm using FB 4, and I then tried upgrading the SDK (only) to 4.5. This fixed the disappearing axis values problem and all seemed to be working correctly. However...

I started to notice that sometimes (very randomly and sporadically) just one or two of the axis values would disappear. Furthermore other Label components not related to charts would also disappear, all seemingly at random and never more than just one or two at a time.

So, the question is: What's happening?

Seems to me like an underlying embedded font problem, but what? And how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Some labels just randomly disappear. Looks like Flex forgets to render some parts of the display list. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Flex SDK version 4.6